Counting the number of occurrences of a number in a list without using loops (for or while)
For example there is a list like A = [7 , 77 , 777 , 717]. I want to count the number of occurrences of the digit 7 in the list, but without using any loops. It should output 8. (7 occurred 8 times). Does anyone know how to do this? I tried to do it by loops but couldn't find a way to do it without any loops (if it's even possible).

Does the map function and list comprehension count as a loop for you?

what, exactly, do you mean by "without a loop"?

Yeah, do built-in function/methods count as "loops"? Or just that you don't want to write for- and while- loops yourself?

I meant whitout any for or while. Sorry for misinformation

One way is to just convert it into string and count
A = [7 , 77 , 777 , 717]

str(A).count('7')

#output
8


I mean, this uses a loop internally...

Thanks ! I'm wondering how I couldn't see that
